# SQL - Return rows matching all values from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

Title might not be massively helpful on this one so I'll try and explain it as best I can.

Assume two tables.

```
Product (ProductID, Name)
ProductCategory (ID, ProductID, CategoryID)
```

and a third temporary table containing a list of CategoryIDs to match.

```
MatchTable(CategoryID)
```

I want to use the contents of MatchTable to return the products that have all of the associated categories.   IE.

```
Product 1: Associated with categories 1 and 2.
Product 2: Associated with categories 2 and 3.
Product 3: Associated with categories 1, 2 and 3.
```

If MatchTable contains 1 and 2, I want to return products 1 and 3 because they match the criteria.  If MatchTable contains 2 then all products would be returned.

The code for returning a product that matches any of the values in MatchTable is easy, but I can't seem to get the syntax right for the products that match all.

Comment: lets see what you have so far.

Comment: This is usually referred to as "relational division".

Comment: Seems this question is very similar to what I'm looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019343/complicated-sql-query-finding-items-matching-multiple-diferent-foreign-keys

I will look there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I'd test a match count vs rows in the matchtable

```
select p.ProductID, max(p.Name)
from Product p
inner join ProductCategory c on c.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join MatchTable m on m.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
group by p.ProductID
having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from MatchTable)
```

### See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdb78/2/0)