# Fetching products matching multiple attribute filters (entity attribute value)

Tags: php, mysql, join, filter, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to add the possibility to add multiple filters when fetching products from a database that has a basic entity-attribute-value model. The filters are based on attribute values like:

- Colors: Green, Red
- Sizes: Small, Large

I have no problems with a single filter, but I don't know how to approach multiple filters at once.

---

**EXAMPLE DATA**: (reduced version)

[SQL file with this example structure & data](https://textuploader.com/dnugt)

Table **products**:

```
id name
1  jacket
2  shirt
```

Table **product_variants**:

```
id product_id
1  1
2  2
3  2
```

Table **attributes**:

```
id name
1  colors
2  sizes
```

Table **attribute_value**:

```
id attribute_id value
1  1            green
2  1            red
3  2            small
4  2            large
```

Table **variant_details**:

```
id product_variant_id attribute_value_id
1  1                  3                    (jacket - small)
2  2                  1                    (shirt - green)
3  2                  3                    (shirt - small)
4  3                  1                    (shirt - green)
5  3                  4                    (shirt - large)
```

---

For this example, the three variants would be:

- Jacket (small)
- Shirt (green & small)
- Shirt (green & large)

---

**THE GOAL**:

I want to pass the ids for the attribute values and get the products matching ALL said attribute values, for example:

```
products.php?attr=1&4
```

Should fetch products that are green(1) AND large(4), for the example only the third variant matches the criteria, so the desired result would be:

```
product_id product_desc
2          shirt
```

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**:

I don't think it'll be much help but I have this for a single attribute:

```
products.php?attr=1
```

Should yield anything that has the attribute value green (1):

```
SELECT products.id, products.desc, attribute_value.value FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_variants ON products.id = product_variants.product_id
LEFT JOIN variant_details ON variant_details.product_variant_id = product_variants.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_value ON attribute_value.id = variant_details.attribute_value_id
WHERE attribute_value.id = 1
GROUP BY products.id
```

The problem with this is, before the **WHERE** clause, this is what it produces:

```
id name    value
1  jacket  small
2  shirt   green
2  shirt   small
2  shirt   green
2  shirt   large
```

and I don't know how to filter those rows that have the value column both green & large, for example. I'm thinking the approach I'm taking for the query is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the input to the SQL? PS There is an obvious view to reconstitute a straightforward non-EAV table from EAV tables. (EAV tables are metadata tables for some straightforward tables.) Then there is an obvious query on those views to give what you want. Find those queries. PS The preferred SQL demo site is sqlfiddle.com if it suits your purposes.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments philipxy.
1.- Finding the queries to convert EAV tables to straightforward: Great idea! I'll look into that.
2.- Text not links: Got it. I decided to link the sql since it seemed to be too much and the tables where already described here, but will take into consideration. 3.- Types of JOIN: Will look into that with more details, thanks again!

Comment: The view(s) and/or result you want for this query might be EAV. Maybe like "product P variant V has attribute A value X". But you haven't clarified how the input filter data enters the SQL. And it's not all that clear what a "match" to it would be. Characterize a table (base or query result) via a statement template parameterized by column names--its *(characteristic) predicate*---where rows making a true statement go in the table. PS The table of subrow values appearing in one table with all subrow values appearing in another table is the result of Codd's original [tag:relational-division].

Comment: Likely this is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. (Your question doesn't yet contain such a clear statement of your output rows in terms of base rows & some form of input/filter rows.)

Comment: [SQL - Return rows matching all values from a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22379865/3404097)

Comment: That last link seems to cover the same principle of what I want to achieve here and applying it to my case seems to be working so far, will test it a little bit more and if everything is alright I'll add it as an answer for future reference. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working **in a way** with the following query:

```
SELECT products.id, products.desc FROM products
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM product_variants
LEFT JOIN variant_details ON variant_details.product_variant_id = product_variants.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_value ON attribute_value.id = variant_details.attribute_value_id
WHERE product_variants.product_id = products.id AND attribute_value.id = 1
)
AND EXISTS
(
SELECT * FROM product_variants
LEFT JOIN variant_details ON variant_details.product_variant_id = product_variants.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_value ON attribute_value.id = variant_details.attribute_value_id
WHERE product_variants.product_id = products.id AND attribute_value.id = 4
)
```

I say **in a way** because it will return all products that have every requested attribute in **one or more** of its **variants**.

**Example**:

Take a single product, a shirt that comes in two colors and two sizes, its variants could be:

- shirt (green & small)
- shirt (green & large)
- shirt (red & small)

Notice the absence of a red & large variant. If I do the above query with red & large it would still match this product because one of its variants has 'red' and another has 'large'.

I decided to add this as an answer instead of an edit because it accomplishes the goal of matching a product with two (or more) attributes but I'd still like to see an answer where the result is restricted to match a single variant of the product, or perhaps another way to achieve this.